# Faster way to decrease some items in a vector in Matlab

Tags: performance, algorithm, matlab, vector

I'm looking for a faster way to do decrease the value of certain numbers in a vector in Matlab, for example I've this vector:

> Vector a=[1 21 35 44 45 67 77 83 93 100]

Then I have to remove the elements 35,45,77, so:

> RemoveVector b=[3,5,7]
>   RemoveElements c=[35,45,77]

After remove the elements, the should be:

> Vector=[1 21 43 65 80 90 97]

**Note that besides remove the element, all the next elements decrease their values in 1**, I've this code in Matlab:

```
a(:,b) = [];
b = fliplr(b);
for i=1:size(a,2)
    for j=1:size(c,2)
        if(a(1,i)>=c(1,j))
            a(1,i) = a(1,i) -1;
        end
    end
end
```

But is too slow, m0=2.8*10^-3 seconds, there is a faster algorithm? I believe with matrix operations could be faster and elegant.

Comment: Your code does not produce the output `[1 21 43 65 80 90 97]`, which behaviour is intended?

Comment: Sorry, i've corriged the code, this give me [1 21 43 65 80 90 97] but i want to improve the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Geoff has a good overall approach, but the adjustment can be done in `O(n)` not `O(n*k)`:

```
adjustment = zeros(size(a));
adjustment(b(:)) = 1;

a = a - cumsum(adjustment);
a(b(:)) = [];
```

Comment: Thank you, I've proved the code, the time was 7.426*10^-5 seconds

Answer (score 1):

I think prior to removing the elements from `a` whose indices are given in `b`, the code could do all the decrementing first

```
% copy a
c = a;

% iterate over each index in b
for k=1:length(b)
    % for all elements in c that follow the index in b (so b(k)+1…end)
    % subtract one
    c(b(k)+1:end) = c(b(k)+1:end) - 1;
end

% now remove the elements that correspond to the indices in b
c(b) = [];
```

Try the above and see what happens!

Comment: Thank you, I've proved the code, the time was 1.2648*10^-4 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Thank so much to Geoff and Ben for yours answer, I've proved both answers by this way:

```
tic
a=[1 21 35 44 45 67 77 83 93 100];
b=[3 5 7];
%Code by Geoff
c = a;
for k=1:length(b)
    % for all elements in c that follow the index in b (so b(k)+1…end)
    % subtract one
    c(b(k)+1:end) = c(b(k)+1:end) - 1;
end
c(b) = [];
m1 = toc;
```

and

```
tic
a=[1 21 35 44 45 67 77 83 93 100];
b=[3 5 7];
%Code by Ben
adjustment = zeros(size(a));
adjustment(b(:)) = 1;
a = a - cumsum(adjustment);
a(b(:)) = [];
m2 = toc;
```

The results in my machine were m1=1.2648*10^-4 seconds and m2=7.426*10^-5 seconds, the second code is faster, my first code gives m0 = 2.8*10^-3 seconds .